# Infragistics - Ultrawebgrid - Add dropdown list which fetches values from another table

Tags: asp.net, infragistics

I have an Ultrawebgrid in which I display two columns. On click of second column (any row in it) I want a drop down to appear with values from an another table.

The version which we are using is Infragistics2.WebUI.Misc.v7.3, Version=7.3.20073.38.

I'm struggling, tried everything but it isnt working:

Code is:

```
    Me.ultrawebgrid1.Columns(1).Type = ColumnType.DropDownList
    Me.ultrawebgrid1.Columns(1).ValueList.ValueListItems.Clear()
    Me.ultrawebgrid1.Columns(1).ValueList.DataSource = dsGetEmployees
    Me.ultrawebgrid1.Columns(1).ValueList.DataMember = "EmployeeId"
    Me.ultrawebgrid1.Columns(1).ValueList.DisplayMember = "EmployeeName"
    Me.ultrawebgrid1.Columns(1).ValueList.DataBind()

                 <igtbl:UltraWebGrid ID="ultrawebgrid1" runat="server"
                        DataSourceID="dsGetEmployeeHistory" Height="473px" Width="100%">
                        <Bands>
                            <igtbl:UltraGridBand>
                                <Columns>
                                    <igtbl:UltraGridColumn BaseColumnName="EmployeeId" IsBound="True"
                                        Key="EmployeeId" Width="125px">
                                        <Header Caption="Employee ID">
                                        </Header>
                                    </igtbl:UltraGridColumn>

                                      <igtbl:UltraGridColumn BaseColumnName="EmployeeName"  IsBound="True" Key="EmployeeName" Type="DropDownList" width="250px" >
                                          <Header Caption="Employee Name">
                                                <RowLayoutColumnInfo OriginX="1" />
                                           </Header>
                                           <Footer>
                                                <RowLayoutColumnInfo OriginX="1" />
                                            </Footer>
                                        </igtbl:UltraGridColumn>
                                </Columns>
                                <AddNewRow View="Top" Visible="Yes">
                                </AddNewRow>
                            </igtbl:UltraGridBand>
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you could follow the Infragistics Forum Thread regarding the very same matter here:

http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/73188/370274.aspx#370274

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue...

Users did not know the cell data was editable and the dropdown list would not appear until you pressed a key (which resulted in changing the value)

after many searches, and many topics on using a templated column... i discovered this little trick:

my original column code for the dropdown:

```
Me.gs.Columns.Add("ORIGIN", "Origin")
Me.gs.Columns(Me.gs.Columns.Count - 1).BaseColumnName = "Origin.Id"
Me.gs.Columns(Me.gs.Columns.Count - 1).Type = ColumnType.DropDownList
Me.gs.Columns(Me.gs.Columns.Count - 1).ValueList.Style.TextOverflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
Me.gs.Columns(Me.gs.Columns.Count - 1).ValueList.Style.Font.Name = "Verdana"
Me.gs.Columns(Me.gs.Columns.Count - 1).ValueList.Style.Font.Size = FontUnit.XXSmall
Me.gs.Columns(Me.gs.Columns.Count - 1).ValueList.DisplayMember = "FriendlyAddress"
Me.gs.Columns(Me.gs.Columns.Count - 1).ValueList.ValueMember = "Id"
Me.gs.Columns(Me.gs.Columns.Count - 1).ValueList.DataBind(ShippingRetrieval.GetAllPlants(MP.CacheGet("SESSION")), Nothing, "FriendlyAddress", "Id")
```

And now... the trick...

before adding the first column, when i add a band:

```
'add columns to grid
Me.gs.Bands(0).Key = "SHIPMENT"
Me.gs.Bands(0).CellClickAction = CellClickAction.Edit '<<<< added this
```

and not when i tab into the cell, or click on it the dropdown becomes visable to the user, they still have to open the dropdown but at least they know its there